Is "Maybe the mall where the store was located charged a high rent" complex, compound, or simple?

Maybe the mall where the store was located charged a high rent.

Is this sentence compound, simple, and/or complex?

Why?  How would this help you?  Why is this difficult? why is this important for you?


Maybe [the mall [where the store was located]] charged a high rent.

The OP's example has its subordinate clause forming part of the subject and hence is not a complex sentence.  Neither is it a compound sentence.
It is a simple sentence.
complex sentence

A complex sentence is made up of a main clause and a subordinate clause connected to each other with a subordinating conjunction.

compound sentence

A compound sentence is made up of two main clauses connected by a coordinating conjunction.

